# Indesign script to automate GREP Find/Replace

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, character-styles

This question follows on from my previous question on the subject of GREP and find/replace functionality of InDesign. To summarize the situation, my InDesign document has 3 character styles applied to the text at various places: `bold`, `italic`, `bolditalic`. The names of those character styles are self-explanatory.

I want to write a script that looks for text styled with any of the above character styles and wraps them in an appropriate HTML tag. For example, I want all text styled as `bold` to be wrapped in the `<b>...</b>` tags, and so on. In my previous question, the accepted answer by Jongware does an excellent job of explaining how to perform a manual Find/Replace using GREP. Now I wish to automate the process by writing a script to handle it. Here's my first attempt:

```
app.findGrepPreferences=app.changeGrepPreferences=null;
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle="bold";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo="<b>$0</b>";
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();
```

This works except that it only wraps thew first character of the affected text in the given tags and erases the rest. Thus a text like "This is an **example** text." changed to "This is an **e** text." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I got it to work with just one extra line of code. Putting the modified code in here for anyone else to benefit:

```
app.findGrepPreferences=app.changeGrepPreferences=null;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat=".+";
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle="bold";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo="<b>$0</b>";
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();
```

The extra line that was missing from my original snippet is the second one:

`app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat=".+";`

Thanks.

Comment: How do I iterate through each matched character and apply a condition and then replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat=".+";
you should use
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat="(.+)";
because
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo="**$0**";
would put in place of $0 what it is written in () symbols.